# Laravel 5 global variable in views

Tags: laravel-5

I created a GlobalComposer class to get the username in all Views:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class GlobalComposer {
/**
 * Bind data to the view.
 *
 * @param  View  $view
 * @return void
 */
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('username', Auth::user());

}

}
?>
```

I want to get the username from the Database in order to save the user's pictures based on username but the problem is that I get a folder created with id, username, name, email, date created.... all columns... how to specifically get the username with the above class?

Folder creation:

```
public function create(array $data)
{


    File::MakeDirectory('/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/' . $data['username']);

    File::makeDirectory("/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/{$data['username']}/fileuploads",
        $mode = 0755, $recursive = true, $force = false);
    File::makeDirectory("/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/{$data['username']}/photos",
        $mode = 0755, $recursive = true, $force = false);


    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username'=>$data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

    ]);



}
```

thank you

Comment: Please how many folders do you wish to create, something  like this: userFolder/username/fileuploads/photos?

Comment: or userFolder/username/fileuploads and userFolder/username/photos

Comment: or userFolder/username/fileuploads and userFolder/username/photos

Comment: this is also confusing why are you using this `Auth::user()->username` to your view? are you trying to create folder for new or existing user?

Comment: Yes, I want to create 
userFolder/username/fileuploads and userFolder/username/photos

Also I'm using the Auth::user()->username because I want to use it in all my views, all my views depends on the authenticated username

Comment: Now i'm getting an error:

ErrorException in GlobalComposer.php line 16: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: is because you are probably not logged in. `Auth::user()->username` will only work if you are logged it. will modify my answer to add `Auth::check()`

Comment: I'm logged in, when the folder gets created as i told you, the username i'm using populate with the information: id,name,username,email,created_at...

Comment: please add code for `create` form you have in your view. And please explain in detail your application flow. who is creating this form, where are you using Auth::user()->username,

Comment: it's very simple, I want to have the variable "username" to be declared globally whenever i need it in any view, username is a column in the users table on the database, I created a GlobalComposer file where I set the variable to be pointed to user()->username but I'm getting this error "Trying to get property of non-object" when I register all information are stored in DB and also a folder is created with the chosen username in UserFolders but with pictures when I upload it doesn't go to the right username photos folder... so there is the issue

Comment: You access Auth::user()->username);
 Directly in your view

Comment: Do dd(Auth::user()) in your globalcomposer class and see what it holds

Comment: it holds all information about user: id, name, username, email, created_at,updated at.... If I change it to dd(Auth::user()->username); it shows me the logged-in username.

Comment: offcourse that what it should show. `Auth::user()->username` will always show the use name of currently logged in user, if thats not what you want then you need to be very clear and explain in more detail. How are you getting this value `array $data` from a form?

Comment: I already pasted it, check the answer 1, you will see return User::create()

I fixed it, anyway I declared the variable, what I'm trying to do exactly if you could help me out, is that I want to declare the username variable globally so it will be used in every view, how to do that? Because that's what I'm trying to achieve with GlobalComposer

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this if username exists in your users table.

```
public function compose(View $view){

    $view->with('username', Auth::user()->username);

}
```

As for this, what you are doing wrong is the use of recursive, which creates all the folders specified in the path if they don't exists,

Secondly I don't like the idea of creating this folders here `/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/` which outside Laravel app, why not create your folder in `storage` which is also protected from outside world

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    File::makeDirectory("/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/{$data['username']}/fileuploads", $mode = 0755, $recursive = true, $force = false);

    if(File::exists("/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/{$data['username']}/fileuploads")){
        File::makeDirectory("/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/{$data['username']}/photos", $mode = 0755); 
    }



    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username'=>$data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

    ]);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it still create a folder with the user data from DB, id, name, username, email,created_at.....

Comment: do you have a script that creates folder or a package? If you do please let me see the code

Comment: yes I have in a recursive order, I'm trying to create an upload space of pictures for every user

Comment: I need to see the code, you are probably doing something wrong there